# Is it OK for HDD temperature to reach 50C?

Tags: hard-drive

While trying Ubuntu from LiveUSB if one goes to the Disks option and checks the temperature - is it an accurate reading?

My new ThinkPad L450 is showing a 50C - is this normal? while idle it goes down to about 47C but even then I think it is kinda high

Comment: It's kinda high but laptops are often a bit hotter because stuff is cramped together. However to be able to say anything, you should get a baseline reference. You say you use a LiveUSB. That means you also have another operating system. What is it? What do the temperature values say there? Do you have temperature readings in your BIOS menu?

Comment: Jeff Atwood: 55C: http://blog.codinghorror.com/hard-drive-temperatures-be-afraid/ (you KNOW we can trust him ;-) ) Should be between 25 and 45C according to http://www.buildcomputers.net/hdd-temperature.html

Comment: By the way: it would be best to change the topic to something Ubuntu related (like "how can I decrease the temp". Though that might be asked before ;-) )